# Virtualbox Memory Usage

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I never used virtualbox before, I have some questions on how it works. I am using windows and I want to run Linux on the VB. Does it create a partition after installation? How much phsical memory does it use? Is the memory freed after closing the VB. I bought a new laptop and the dealer said that, my warranty would be voided if I do any partition.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, VB doesn't create partition, it uses a virtual disk.
2. You can decide how much physical memory you want to assign to your virtual machine.
3. BTW I strongly recommend you reading [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html).

Comment: Qiu, Thanks for the reply just one more question is the memory freed after exiting VB or will it hold that particular memory I allocated even after exiting.

Comment: When you're closing guest operating system (in your case - Linux), all RAM is being freed, while virtual disk is not being deleted.